# Android recyclerview divider aligned to internal layout views

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, divider

I know this gotta have a simple answer, so here goes:

This is an image of a famous "chat" Android app. My question is how can I simulate the behaviour in red, namely a divider that does not take the parent's screen width, but starts aligned with the text views in the recyclerview item inflated layout?

[image]

I have created a `chatlist_divider.xml` drawable as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<inset xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:insetLeft="80dp"
       android:insetRight="16dp">
    <shape>
        <size android:height="1dp"/>
        <padding
            android:bottom="2dp"
            android:left="8dp"
            android:right="8dp"
            android:top="2dp"/>
        <solid android:color="@color/colorDivider"/>
        <corners android:radius="48dp" />
    </shape>
</inset>
```

and programatically have used it as follows:

```
mRecyclerView.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(getActivity(), R.drawable.chatlist_divider));
```

but ofc the result will not be as perfect as in the image above, because Im playing with the `insetLeft` property of the inset, until it feels right:

[image]

Is this the best that can be done? I wanted a proper and definite alignment to the TextViews inside the inflated layout of each list item, not just trial and error.

(I could also create a `<View>` below the textviews (which are in a Layout of its own) to simulate the divider, but then how can I assign it the .xml drawable?)

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to use `mRecyclerView.addItemDecoration`.

Simply create the divider as a regular View with your drawable xml as background and add it to your item's layout xml.

If you make the root of the layout `RelativeLayout`, you can have the divider `toRightOf="@+id/some_other_view"`, so it's aligned properly with the item's views.

```
<View
    android:id="@+id/divider"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="3dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/my_photo_view"
    android:background="@drawable/chatlist_divider" />
```

Comment: Thank you, how could I forget the background attribute! ^_^

Comment: Not advised. The problem with this is that if you ever intend to add animations or swipe actions, the divider would animate/swipe with the itemView as well. Plus hiding and showing it may have an impact on performance.